# "Meet off" vs "meet on"

Tags: grammaticality

I recently came across an article which read:
A guy I **met off** LinkedIn who is a lawyer explained to me...

It could also have been "A guy I **met on** LinkedIn who is a lawyer..."

Can someone explain the difference between these two and when to use them.

Comment: The *off* phrasing is more colloquial. I don't recommend using it if it does not come naturally.

Comment: Makes sense @MikeGraham

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatical, but the latter is more common and accepted as the standard phrase. But again, MW defines *[off of](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off%20of)*, so it's really a question of using it on audience that you think can assimilate the usage.